# Is there a way that the recommended plugin update window doesn't show?

Tags: android, gradle-plugin

Im doing alot of small applications using Android Studio. I want to always use gradle plugin 3.2.1 even if I know there are newer versions. Each time, i get the request by Android Studio to update my gradle plugin version. I know I can click on "Dont remind me for this project" but I get that each time I create a new project. Is there a template / setting I could use to bypass this window of requesting the update ?

I know that the result of declining the update is that the file workspace.xml in the .idea folder have a new line :

How could I add this line by default ?